# Bitmap Resolution Issue

Tags: android, bitmap, android-custom-view, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I want to need draw high resolution bitmap like 1082*1673 on canvas into center of custom view.i tried to set bitmap center into custom view but my image quality is down because i used BitmapFectory.createscledbitmap.how it possible

i tried to this
           `int startX =(canvasWidth-Whitebitmap.getWidth())/2;
            int startY=(canvasHeight-Whitebitmap.getHeight())/2;
            canvas.translate(mPositionX, mPositionY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,0 , 0, drawPaint);
            canvas.restore();`

Comment: use `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)` method

Comment: so do you know how to construct your `Matrix`?

Comment: Sorry No any idea.

Comment: see `Matrix#setRectToRect()` method

Comment: Thanks @pskink But i want display bitmap on any devices into center of custom view and my bitmap resolution very high. So i want to display bitmap center of custom view without stretch my bitmap

Comment: Current my image display in screen  https://pasteboard.co/I3fGlpP.png

And Actually i want to need display images using this way https://pasteboard.co/I3fWaxP.png

Comment: as i sad use `Matrix#setRectToRect()` method

Comment: i tried but not set bitmap properly center into canvas using #setRectToRect method

Comment: so what you exactly did? what was your code? and what was the result?

Comment: I want to need display bitmap center into canvas like this https://pasteboard.co/I3fWaxP.png

Comment: so what you exactly did? what was your code? and what was the result?

Comment: Bitmap was stretch..I think my #reacttoreact method was not work

Comment: am i to ask the same questions for a 3rd time?

Comment: I tried to use this way But how to used in  draw method for draw bitmap on canvas

RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

Comment: when / where do you call it? inside `onSizeChanged` ?

Comment: Thank You @pskink  It's working now. But color not filled into bitmap becaused my original bitmap resolution is high so color not filled into specific pixel into bitmap

If i used this bitmap using compress method and fill color into bitmap so the color is completely fill.. What  is mistack?

Comment: color? what color?

Comment: Any color like this Black,White,Pink ...

Comment: sorry but i have no idea what you mean here... post **small** image or something

Comment: I want to need like this........https://pasteboard.co/I3mPrXD.jpg

Comment: so this is a completely different issue - ask another question then

Comment: Okay @pskink Thank you vary much